# Angular 2 - Multilanguage with Rest Service

Tags: angular, rest, translation

I would like to build a Multilanguage angular app. This app will be part of multiple other applications and services and there er have a central API for translations. Just a simple rest api where you send a key or collection of keys and language and you get the translations.
This is used in mails, and other applications.

Can i somehow use this with angular2? or do i have to use the i18n described in the angular docs?

Whats with ngx-translate? Could i use this also for that? Like that i create an endpoint at my translation api which returns an en.json file with all translations regarding the app?
If i do it like this, how will this affect the language change performance? Will the change between languages take some time or are all available languages prefetched?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using ngx-translate which provides http-loader for fetching translations. You can also use lazy loading for translations to increase performance and load file per module.

Check it out https://medium.com/@TuiZ/how-to-split-your-i18n-file-per-lazy-loaded-module-with-ngx-translate-3caef57a738f